# Optional OneToOne relation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Currently working on a project where we want to extract with Hibernate the following datamodel (model is a little bit simplified). We have a class A which contains some optional data which is stored in class B

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "A")
public class Country {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String someCommon;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private B details;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    private String someDetail;
}
```

Fetching data works fine, except that when class B is not found for some instance of A, Hibernate does an extra query for that specific instance to retrieve the details of A. I.e in the logs these are the queries executed:

```
select a0_.id as id1_0_0_, b1_.id as id1_1_1_, a0_.some_common as some_common2_0_0_, b1_.some_detail as some_detail_2_1_1_ from a a0_ left outer join b b1_ on a0_.id=b1_.id

select b0_.id as id1_1_0_, b0_.some_detail as some_detail_2_1_0_ from b b0_ where b0_.id=?
```

Where in the second query the id is set to the id of the instance which does not have details.

So it looks like Hibernate is not supporting optional OneToOne relationships in an efficient manner. Any ideas on how to force Hibernate not doing the second query but just accepting the details are null?

Comment: Please refer https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/ANN-725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get rid of second query as you mentioned in hibernate because If the association is optional, Hibernate has no way to know if an address exists for a given person without issuing a query. so closest thing you can do is to call for second query only when its intended:

So as to avoid second query you have to opt for **Lazy Loading**:

To do that change your mapping to set optional to false and lazy loading will be on on details:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private B details;
```

Lazy loading makes sure details will be fetched only when its intended.